# Do something if selected Cells are in the same Column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to do something only if selected dgvCells are in the same Column:

```
foreach (DataGridViewCell c in dgvC.SelectedCells)
if (c.ColumnIndex is the same) // how to say this ?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seen no reply for sometime, here is my solution, I don't think it optimized enough, but I think it will do the job

```
int columnIndex = dgvC.SelectedCells[0].ColumnIndex;
bool sameCol = true;
for(int i=0;i<dgvC.SelectedCells.Count;i++)
    {
        if(dgvC.SelectedCells[i].ColumnIndex != columnIndex)
         {
           sameCol = false;
           break;
          }
     }
 if (sameCol)
     {
       MessageBox.Show("Same Column");
     }
  else
     {
       MessageBox.Show("Not same column");
     }
```

EDIT:
You can also try:

```
    int columnIndex = dgvC.SelectedCells[0].ColumnIndex;
    if (dgvC.SelectedCells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().Any(r => r.ColumnIndex != columnIndex))
    {
        //Not same
    }
    else
    {
        //Same
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use GroupBy to make sure that cells are from the same column

```
if(dgvC.SelectedCells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
            .GroupBy(c => c.ColumnIndex).Count() == 1)
{
   foreach (DataGridViewCell c in dgvC.SelectedCells)
     //your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something basic like this should work:

```
        Boolean allCells = true;
        int colIndex = dgvC.SelectedCells[0].ColumnIndex;

        foreach (DataGridViewCell c in dgvC.SelectedCells)
        {
            if(c.ColumnIndex != colIndex)
            {
                allCells = false;
            }
        }

        if(allCells)
        {
            //do stuff here
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
for (int i=0; i < dgvC.SelectedCells.Count; i++ )
{
    int currentCellColumnIndex = dgvC.SelectedCells[i].ColumnIndex;
    for (int j=i+1; j < dgvC.SelectedCells.Count-1; j++) 
    {
         if(currentCellColumnIndex ==  dgvC.SelectedCells[j])
         {
            //Same column 
            //dgvC.SelectedCells[i] and all dgvC.SelectedCells[j] have same column

         } 
    }
}
```